# Hibernate composite id merge

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, composite-id

I'm using Hibernate with JPA and have a relation like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "first")
public class First {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "first")
private List<Availability> availabilities;
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "second")
public class Second {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "second")
private List<Availability> availabilities;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="availability")
public class Availability implements Serializable {
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "first_id")
private First first;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "second_id")
private Second second;

@Column(name = "availability")
private Integer availability;

...
hashcode and equals
}
```

I want to manage these 3 entities separately. First and Second work fine, but when I try to merge() the third one postgresql gets a null value instead of the id's and constraint violation exception is thrown. Why? Can I even use merge on this entity to add new rows to the table?

update:
The merge is something like this:

```
public Availability setAvailability(Availability a) {
return em.merge(a);
}
```

where the availability is deserialized from front-end (just to mention, the collections of "key" classes are detached in it).

Comment: Hi! Post a slice of code where you give an example of how you merge that entity.. maybe could be only a problem of Cascading merge operation

Comment: Done, but it's nothing special. I am using this kind of return-merge operations to add/update rows in many places in the project, thought it would work for this entity too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by avoiding the use of Composite ID. After rethinking the problem I found out that this case I actually can use an unique constraint.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "availabilities", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "first_id", "second_id" }) })
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "availabilities_sequence", sequenceName =     "availabilities_sequence")
public class Availability implements IAvailability, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2977047920673617888L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "availabilities_sequence")
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "first_id", nullable=false)
private First first;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "second_id", nullable=false)
private Second second;

@Column(name = "availability", nullable=false)
private Integer availability;

...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You already solved your issue, but I leave here a suggestion for users that need to use multiple-columns primary keys and can't change the database.

Apparently, using multiple @Id annotations by themselves produces an inconsistency when trying to merge: you assign all fields, and then **during the merge the fields annotated with @Id get assigned null values** (and the merge fails). I can guess an explanation: hibernate doesn't expect there to be a non-managed object with assigned @Ids; but this is an issue only with multiple column primary keys, so it seems to be a bug.

Note: calling **persist** instead of merge works (but in some cases you would duplicate rows or get database constraint errors, because the primary key in this case is checked only at database level).

I solved a similar issue using @IdClass. In your old code you would have to:

1. Create a class (for example **AvailabilityId**) with fields **first** and **second** (matching exactly the fields annotated with @Id in class Availability), and overriding **equals** and **hashCode** methods
2. No annotations are required in AvailabilityId other than @Override (by the way, if you use @Column on both Availability and AvailabilityId fields you can get monstruous errors). This has not to be an entity or a table, it is a POJO.
3. Annotate class Availability with @IdClass(AvailabilityId.class)

That should be it. Sorry for being 3 years late, but if you got rid of your multiple column primary key you are in a better world now anyway.

I tried @EmbeddedId but it broke a couple of other requirements (easy json->object conversion and queries working both in SQL and HQL with minor adjustments).