# Hibernate merge or saveOrUpdate

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

I am writing an application where I store the incoming stream of data into jdbc using hibernate. I tried using saveOrUpdate for that. But I am getting following exception:

*"org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"*

I searched through internet and found that instead of update, I should use merge().

But what if I need to insert object if it is not present. Merge is not working for this usecase.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On the contrary, the `MERGE` statements performs an `INSERT` if the key doesn't exists, an `UPDATE` otherwise. You'll can still get similar exception as above if you merge from several independent sessions, but the probability will be significanty lower that if the application makes the decision to insert or to update. Check the [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement for details.

Comment: Hi @MarmiteBomber , I am actually getting the following error while using merge() - "org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement 
caused by - java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'xyz' cannot be null" .
I tried to find solution for the same, but unable to find it. Im my table I have 3 colums that contribute to PK.

Comment: Well this is a minor problem easy to solve by stopping to insert/update the column to `NULL` (i.e. use `nvl` and set the value to *unknow* or so) or by altering the the table and allowing the column to be nullable. If you search for above phareses you should find details easily.

Comment: But when I am trying to insert my column is not null and it is part of primary key.

Comment: Also I am using merge(object) method. From my understanding it when doesn't find the object it creates new by specifying null values and then update it. But I am unable to find solution to tweak this.

Comment: You problem has nothing to do with a database, you must clarify the logic behind first. Basically you are trying to process some record, but you **do not know which one** as you do not have all parts of the PK. So you have two possibilities, either discard all such rows from the processing or make the decision that all `NULL` are identical and supply some constant value instead of the `NULL` *before the MERGE*.

Comment: I am trying to process record with all PK known. I have all parts of PK with me. But inserting it to db using merge() is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872270/hibernate-composite-id-merge - this post solved the problem. It was because of composite PK.